# AttributeError: 'Misc' object has no attribute 'bot' - When adding a cog

Tags: python, discord.py

INSIDE MAIN DISCORDBOT FILE

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import json
import os
import asyncio

def get_prefix(bot, message):
    with open("jsonfiles/prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
        
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
            
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, intents=discord.Intents.all())

with open("textfiles/keys.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    bot_token = lines[0]
    bot_invite_url = lines[1]

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Successfully connected to Discord.")
    print("To invite, copy and paste this link into url and go from there. ", bot_invite_url)
    
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open("jsonfiles/prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
        
    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = "="
    
    with open("jsonfiles/prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@bot.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open("jsonfiles/prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
        
    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))
    
    with open("jsonfiles/prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4) 
        
async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")   

    
async def main():
    async with bot:
        await load()
        await bot.start(bot_token)

asyncio.run(main())
```

INSIDE COG I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

class Misc(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        bot = self.bot
        
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Misc.py is online.")
        
    @commands.command(aliases=["8ball", "eightball"])
    async def magic_eight_ball(self, ctx, *, question):
        with open("textfiles/responses.txt", "r") as f:
            random_responses = f.readlines()
            
        response = random.choice(random_responses)
        
        await ctx.send(response)
        
#the error occurs here (i at least think)
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Misc(bot))
```

Inside this code, I am receiving an Error that looks like this:

```
  File "d:\DiscordBot\cogs\misc.py", line 7, in __init__
    bot = self.bot
          ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Misc' object has no attribute 'bot'
```

I have another cog that works as it is supposed to! And I have went over both files and discovered that everything in the cog that's causing an error is correctly written. Is this a bug? Or is there something I am doing wrong that I just do not see...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the wrong way around

```py
bot = self.bot
```

You're now saying:

> "The variable `bot` should be equal to the attribute `bot` stored in this class"

However, at that point the attribute doesn't exist yet, because you've never created it. You want to do it the other way around, and set the value of the *attribute* to the value of the *argument*.

```py
self.bot = bot
```